# how to protect wso2 api manager login page from CSP(content security policy) attack?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, content-security-policy, wso2

I used onmouseover=alert("") in ui segment of login page wso2 and we can't login anymore and this is a type of CSP attack. what is the solution friends and how we cant prevent attacks like this?

[image]